# Error forward engineer SQL DB to phpmyadmin ERROR

Tags: mysql

before you say do some google i did for 1 and half hours straight and i still haven't found a fix for this issue please if you have any knowledge about this issue share your answers

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Doctors_department1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`department_name' at line 10
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `GPMS_DB`.`Doctors`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `GPMS_DB`.`Doctors` (
          `id` INT NOT NULL,
          `F_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          `L_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
          `department_name` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `department_name`),
          INDEX `fk_Doctors_department1_idx` (`department_name` ASC) VISIBLE,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_Doctors_department1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`department_name`)
            REFERENCES `GPMS_DB`.`department` (`name`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 8 succeeded, 1 failed
```

Comment: What's your MySQL server version? `VISIBLE` and `INVISIBLE` was introduced in verison 8.0.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast the phpmyadmin is 5.6.34-log and the SQL Workbench is 5.6

Comment: That doesn't matter. What matters is the server version.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast its like i said server version 5.6

Comment: You never said that. PhpMyAdmin is not the server, it's a rich client written in PHP. Anyway, if you're running a 5.6 server but use 8.0 features, then there's your problem.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast my apologies my knowledge is low on these stuff anyway the server is 5.6 and i'm currently updating hoping it fix's the issue

Comment: @Cobra_Fast i've tried updating the SQL server but that does not seem to fix the problem

Comment: Are you sure you upgraded the server? There seems to be some confusion here about what `phpmyadmin` `mysql workbench` and `mysql server` is. The first two are clients that connect to the third (the server). The message you are getting is independent of the client and is 100% from the server.

Comment: Also @Cobra_Fast I'm not super familiar with mysql CREATE table DDL differences in versions. What is the 8+ feature that is present in this DDL (just for my own knowlege).

Comment: @Cobra_Fast i just fixed it the problem was that the SQL server i was using was out of date

Comment: @JNevoll  i just fixed it the problem was that the SQL server i was using was out of date